# Why do bind and mysqli_query show different types of data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch some data from a table using **mysql bind** concept. The queries work but I don't get the expected results. Here's what I've tried and observed:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");

//USING BIND
/*$query= mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM car WHERE id=1");
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
$result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode(array("fileds"=>$rows));*/

//NORMAL WAY
$query="SELECT * FROM car WHERE id=1";
$queryrun=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryrun)){
    $rows[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode(array("fileds"=>$rows));
?>
```

The results are:

Bind:

```
{"fileds":[{"id":1,"Name":"dfgdf","Brand":"dfgd","Model":"dfg","driver_id":1,"bools":1}]}
```

Normal:

```
{"fileds":[{"id":"1","Name":"dfgdf","Brand":"dfgd","Model":"dfg","driver_id":"1","bools":"1"}]}
```

So, as you can see, the **bools** key has output **1** and **"1"** respectively. But I want only the **2nd** one, that is string, USING **BIND**.

Is there any way to fix? Or am I doing something wrong?

[The data type of **bools** is INT]

Comment: No, there's no way

Comment: So that means this is considered better? Getting an integer instead of string?